# RxJS and ANGULAR: Restructure/reorder json data based on a particular 'key' using RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm fetching this JSON data which is an array of objects and I need to restructure/reorder it so I can render information in my component.

**present structure:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Rahul",
    "class": 3,
    "gender": "M",
    "section": "B",
    "rollNumber": "1231",
    "sports": [
      "Badminton",
      "Chess"
    ],
    "age": 7
  },
  {
    "name": "Rajat",
    "class": 5,
    "gender": "M",
    "section": "C",
    "rollNumber": "123122",
    "sports": [
      "Chess"
    ],
    "age": 9
  },
]
```

**desired structure:**

```
class 4
   section A
       name
   section B
       name
class 5
   section A
       name
   section B
       name
.
.
.
```

I have tried it using groupBy() and mergeMap() in rxjs [here: example 2](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html)

**This is my angular service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, from, of, zip, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { groupBy, mergeMap, toArray, map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {
  const studentURL = 'https://student-management-api-1u3cd4j7s.now.sh/students';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  public getStudents(): Observable<any> {
    const studentList = this.http.get(this.studentURL);
    .tap(result => result.json());
    from(studentList)
    .pipe(
      groupBy(studentList => studentList.class),
      mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
    )
    .subscribe(console.log('studentList', studentList));
    return studentList;
  }
}
```

**component.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ConfigService } from '../config/config.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-class-component',
  templateUrl: './class-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./class-component.component.css']
})
export class ClassComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  students: object;
  constructor(private data: ConfigService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getStudents().subscribe(data => {
      this.students = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

**component.html file**

```
<div class='container'>
  <ul *ngFor="let student of students; let i = index">
    <h3> Class {{ student.class }}</h3>
    <li *ngFor="let section of students; let i = index">
      <h5> section {{ student.section}}</h5>
      <!-- <a href='#' *ngFor="let name of students">{{student.name}}</a> -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I think it would be better to restructure/reorder in the service itself after the fetch. Not sure where I am going wrong and what I am missing.

Comment: what's the result that you see in console.log

Comment: I see two things: a) ERROR in src/app/config/config.service.ts:16:5 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

16     .tap(result => result.json());
b) fetched json data which I have console.log in another component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**: you will get an array which emits the whole array for groupBy to work you need to emit all values so here with switchMap and from we will emit all entries of array

**Step 2**: groupBy will give another observable which you need to merge to see the grouped result. All groups will now emit as a value

In the below example there can be 2 groups class 3 and 5 so the final result in your subscribe function will be called twice one with class 3 another with class 5.

**Step 3:** If you want to go deeper repeat groupBy and mergeMap

```
this.http.get(this.studentURL).pipe(
  switchMap(val => from(val)),
  groupBy(studentList => studentList.class),
  mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
  map(studentList => ({['class' + studentList[0].class]: studentList }))
)
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8jlvij?file=index.ts

---

#### Update 2: solution

**Service**:

```
public getStudents(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>(this.studentURL)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(val => from(val)),
    groupBy(studentList => studentList.class),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
    map(studentList => ({
      [studentList[0].class]: studentList.reduce((sections, student) => ({...sections, [student.section]: [...(sections[student.section] || []), student]}), {})
    })),
    scan((response, studentList) => ({...response, ...studentList}), {})
  );
}
```

**Component**:

```
students$: Observable<any>; 
// you can hook up the observable here 
// in template you can use the the async pipe 
// to subscribe to the observable

ngOnInit() {
  this.students$ = this.service.getStudents();
}
```

**Template**:

```
<div class='container'>
  <ul *ngFor="let classItem of students$ | async | keyvalue; let i = index">
    <li> Class {{ classItem.key }}</li>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let sectionItem of classItem.value | keyvalue; let i = index">
          <h5> Section {{sectionItem.key}}</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#' *ngFor="let student of sectionItem.value ">{{student.name}}</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Updated Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tspamr

Comment: can you provide some explanation please. It would help to understand your solution. and also, how do I go even deeper in the json

Comment: your solution works. but I still them to be inside an array so that I can iterate it later in my partial. getting this error browser console. ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: can you post your template

Comment: done. I just updated the post with component.ts and component.html file code

Comment: updated code without manually subscribing in the component. It is the recommended way

Comment: can you please add some explanation for UPDATE 2-> without manual subscribe.